# Express server fetches HTML5 video on every loop

Tags: javascript, html, express, html5-video, webm

I have a simple HTML5 video (`.webm` extension) that I'm calling with:

```
 <video src="/vid/better_test.webm" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
```

In my ExpressJS (Node) server logs, I'm seeing a `GET` request for the video every time it loops:

[image: HTML5 video keeps getting fetched]

This is a huge amount of bandwidth! How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111382/under-what-conditions-will-the-browser-cache-video-files this might help